# Close html tag inside the "if" condition with xslt language

Tags: html, xslt

I would like to be able to close html tags based on some conditions:

```
 <xsl:for-each test="">
 <table>
  <tbody>
 <tr><td></td></tr>
 <xsl:if test="position() mod 35 = 0 ">

        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</tbody>]]></xsl:text>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"><![CDATA[</table>]]></xsl:text>
 </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

In IE and Edge, this works fine, but not in Firefox:

[image]

Comment: An XSLT stylesheet must be a well-formed XML document. If you have an opening tag for `table`, you must also have a closing one. There should be no need for a hack like this. Look for a different solution for whatever the real problem here is.

Comment: I will try to find some different solution .. Thanks for the advice

Comment: This is a guess, but does this question help (Substitute the div for table tags): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9908488/xslt-for-each-wrapping-every-nth-item-in-a-div

Comment: I will try this solution of the divs so as not to have to use the tables .. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are hitting a major problem.
See [`<xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes">` not working](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=98168) in the Mozilla Bug Tracker.

This means that Mozilla Firefox has not supported `disable-output-escaping` for 18 years.

Comment: disable-output-escaping is a terrible hack, and Mozilla have done the user community a great service by not implementing it.

Answer (score 0):

XSLT works on node trees, not on tags. You can't write half a node to a result tree. Writing tags directly using disable-output-escaping only works if your XSLT transformer is closely coupled to a serializer, which severely limits your options.

It looks like you're trying to split a sequence of items into groups of 35. Grouping in XSLT 1.0 is tricky, but there's a vast literature on the subject: just search on "XSLT Grouping". For fixed-size grouping, see for example [Transforming XML to group fields into columns with XSLT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34898601/transforming-xml-to-group-fields-into-columns-with-xslt).