# XSL-FO multiple tables inline

Tags: xsl-fo

I am trying to place two tables in line. Is there a tag to place two or more tables in one big table so they wouldn't be each on the new line? Recently I found the solution and successfully created what I described in my question, but for now I can't remember and even find the same solution.

Comment: may be you could use a two column table, like here : [Two adjacent tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5310746/two-adjacent-tables-in-body-region-each-with-two-columnsxsl-fo?rq=1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, solution was pretty simple.
I created one big table and put each of my tables in fo:table-row and fo:table-cell tags of newly created table.